# Plot a convex set

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider set A and function  that are defined as follows:
$A = \{ [,]^T \hspace{0.2cm}| \hspace{0.2cm}^2 + ^2 ≤ 1 \},\hspace{1cm}  ([, ]^T) = [1, 2][,]^T + 1.$

Then what are the members of set B defined as follows:

$B= \{ ([, ]^T) \hspace{0.2cm}| \hspace{0.2cm}[,]^T \in A \}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is about finding the range of a linear function
$$
f(x,y)=x+2y+1
$$

on the unit circle $A$, $x^2+y^2\le 1$. You can take the family of level curves (straight lines) $x+2y+1=k$ and find the values of $k$ for which the line touches the circle. Those will correspond to the max and min values of $f$. If you set up the system $x+2y+1=k$, $x^2+y^2=1$ you get a quadratic equation for $y$
$$
5y^2-4(k-1)y+(k-1)^2-1=0
$$
There is only one intersection iff the discriminant is zero, that is
$$
16(k-1)^2-20[(k-1)^2-1]=0
$$

which gives $k=\pm\sqrt{5}+1$. So the desired range is $B=[-\sqrt{5}+1,\sqrt{5}+1]$.

Comment: Thank you. Why we should just look for one intersection? Also, what would be the members of the new set $C=\{(x,y) | f(x,y) \in B \}$? Are sets $C$ and $A$ the same?

Comment: Level lines of a linear function are a family of parallel lines. The value of the function ($k$) increases in in the direction perpendicular to the lines. The min corresponds to the first time the family touches the circle, the max corresponds to the last time it touches the circle. Therefore you are looking for the two tangents in the given direction of your family of level sets.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. Would you please let me have your response for set C defined in the first comment?

Comment: Actually A and C are different. C would be the whole strip contained between the two tangents to the circle.